# How do I create this legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I am trying to update an existing map in my organization without the original `.mxd` or feature classes.

Its going OK, but the legend is beyond anything I've seen. There's the typical ArcMap legend, and then all this data at the bottom that is essentially records from the attribute table.

Does anyone know if this is possible or if it was maybe imported from another program?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it may be a graphic or table rather than a legend.  Possibly created in another program and imported as an image.

Comment: Please include the version of ArcMap you are running

Comment: Copy paste from excel, 95 percent confident

Comment: It was either created as a text, using Insert > Text , or it was created as a graphic in Illustrator, GIMP, Photoshop, etc...  then exported to a graphic file and then inserted.  This is also done through Insert > Graphic .

Comment: yeah, copy and paste from excel is a little cumbersome, but actually works great in my opinion.

Comment: That could be done by cloning text and line graphic elements in ArcPy. Whether it has is hard to tell.

Comment: Please be aware that questions here should not just state a requirement but should say precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.